# Calculate percentage difference live websocket

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

I am connected to a `Websocket` stream that gives me +100 cryptocurrency prices, live (I get new prices about every 2 seconds). I would like to know, how to calculate the percentage difference between each crypto price on a 5 minutes period, then update it every new minute? I am using React with a native Websocket connection (not socket.io).

I think I would have to "save" (somehow) each crypto price every minute, but how can I do that?

For test purposes, to see if I could update one crypto price every 10 seconds, I tried using `setInterval()` in `.onmessage()` of the socket connection.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Connection : ', connection);
    if (connection) {
        let interval;
        connection.onmessage = evt => {
            interval = setInterval(() => {
                setPrice(crypto.BTCUSDT.price); // price variable is used to display the price of the crypto
                console.log('----- Interval test -----')
                clearInterval(interval);
            }, 6000);
        };  
    }
}, [connection]);
```

This does not work, when `setPrice()` is called for the first time in `setInterval()`, then it's like `setInterval()` is ignored and the price still gets updated around every 2 seconds. Same for the `console.log()`, that gets displayed every 2 seconds and not every 10 seconds.

### ----- EDIT -----

In the `crypto` object, I have a fixed timestamp, incremented every minute. Would someone have any idea how I could use this for this problem ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

<s>I might be wrong, since I don't know the rest of the code, but if your `setInterval` is not inside `useEffect`, then a new interval is created at every render. And the component is re-rendered every time `setPrice` is called. Put the event listeners in `useEffect` and see if that fixes it.</s>

So, I tried something, and this works the way you want. At least, the way I understand you want. The `setPrice` is called once every 10 seconds.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);
  let interval;
  useEffect(() => {
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      setPrice((prev) => prev + 1);
      console.log({ price });
    }, 10000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);
  return <div>{price}</div>;
}
```

Comment: I edited the code. As you can see, `setInterval()` is in fact in `useEffect()`. If you're wondering about the `connection` argument for the `useEffect()`, it runs only once so the `useEffect()` is only called once. I added `console.log('Connection : ', connection)` to make sure, and this logs only once.

Comment: @Tom687 fair enough, but I don't get why you're running `clearInterval` inside the interval callback?

Comment: So the interval doesn't get quicker and quicker. Maybe it is misplaced, but should not change the problem, should it ?

Comment: If I'm right, your current code will only run the interval callback once

Comment: @Tom687 check if my edited answer works for you

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't work inside the `Websocket` listener `onmessage()`. It does outside of it though. But what I need is getting the live stream from the websocket and set an interval on the values it gives me.

Comment: I edited my question. In fact, the `crypto.BTCUSDT` object contains a timestamp incremented every minute. Any idea how I could use it in my case ? Thank you very much

Comment: @Tom687 How about saving the price every time the timestamp is a multiple of 5 minutes?